# How to call a function given a string of that function's name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file `allthetests.py` with a number of small functions defined like this:

```
def test1():
    ##do some stuff
    if (everything_is_awesome):
        return({"status":PASS, "data":"all the data"})

def test2():
    ##do some different stuff
    if (everything_is_bad):
        return({"status":FAIL, "data":"no data"})
```

Then I have another bunch of files which are descriptions of nodes and get imported as dicts like this

```
{"node_type":"action",
"title":"things",
"test":"test2"}
```

Finally I have a third file `main.py` which is in charge of everything. 
In this third file, I want to import `allthetests.py`, load the node descriptions and then call `allthetests.test1()` or `allthetests.test2()` or whatever that case is. I imagine it might look something like this but I'm not really sure where to go from here...

```
import allthetests

cur_node = load_node()

## Doesn't work but...
return_val = allthetests.cur_node['test']()
```

Comment: If you can import `allthetests` into the files defining the dicts, you can just leave the quotes off like `"test":test2`. Functions are objects in Python.

Comment: @MarkRansom how would I go about actually running that function? Would it be just `return_val = curnode['test']` ?

Comment: @Indigo that plus `()` to pass in params. So: `return_val = cur_node['test']()`. Alternately you can do `getattr(allthetests, cur_node)()`